# Acknowledgements section of the paper

Tags: conference, paper-submission, acknowledgement

Conference papers are now double-blind. So when was the acknowledgment part written? If I write an acknowledgment when submitting the paper, isn't it easy to leak information? Is the acknowledgment written after the paper is accepted?
Thanks

Comment: Definitely.  Otherwise, there is nothing to thank, especially if reviewers are nasty.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what do you mean? Is the acknowledgment written after acceptance?

Comment: If I write an acknowledgment when submitting the paper, isn't it easy to leak information? 
Definitely
Is the acknowledgment written after the paper is accepted? Definitely

Comment: The author name is also added after acceptance, isn’t that the exact same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manuscripts should be submitted for double-blind review without acknowledgments, which are added after acceptance in the camera-ready manuscript.